# Need to create sql view accessible by person but this person cant access the database

Tags: azure-sql-database

I have multi tenant azure sql database. I need to create readonly view to one customer to read some data without able to access any other database tables or views. How i can do that

Comment: This may be of use for you; https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/security/row-level-security?view=sql-server-ver15

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try [Azure Data Share](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=a-21ryrpOFY&feature=youtu.be) to share a view with any person you want without giving access to the database.

1. Create a Data Share account.
2. Navigate to your Data Share Overview page.

[image]

3. Select Start sharing your data.
4. Select Create.
5. Fill out the details for your Data Share. Specify a name, description of share contents, and terms of use (optional).

[image]

6. Select Continue
7. To add Datasets to your Data Share, select Add Datasets.

[image]

8. Select the dataset type that you would like to add.

[image]

9. Specify the view you want to share with.
10. In the Recipients tab, enter in the email addresses of your Data Consumer by selecting '+ Add Recipient'.

[image]

11. Select Continue.
12. Set off "Snapshot schedule".
13. In the Review + Create tab, review your Package Contents, Settings, Recipients, and Synchronization Settings. Select Create.

Comment: Thanks Alberto, but he need to access this view from other application through call or api, can he do that using the above method

Answer (score 1):

Alberto Morillo  provided a good way for you.

But from the [Azure Data Share Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-share/overview),  Data share only can help share the view data to the customer, can not receive the request from customer, it's unidirectional.

According your comment, customer want to access the view from other application through call or API,

The answer is no, we can not do that for now without the permission for login or access the database.

Hope this helps.

Comment: In that case which alternative method i can do to achieve that

Comment: @HanyHussein I'm afraid we can't achieve that for now. If there are some good methods, I'm sure we will share to you.  You can accept(mark) it as answer( click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in.). This can be beneficial to other community members. Or you also can still waiting for other suggestions. Thank you.